# friend not getting the private members

Tags: c++, qt, stream, operator-overloading, friend-function

I've a class called `Packet` That I want to serialize with `QDataStream` I overloaded `operator>>` and `operator<<` and in the over loaded function I called `stream << somIntMember` Though Its declared as friend its complaining for Private Variables

```
error: 'int DG::Packet::_state' is private
error: 'DG::Packet::PacketType DG::Packet::_type' is private
```

Here goes my Header.

```
namespace DG{
class Packet{
    public:
    struct CommonHeader{
        public:
            quint32 id;
            QTime time;
            quint32 size;
            PacketType packetType;
        public:
            CommonHeader();
            CommonHeader(quint32 sz, PacketType type);
            friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Packet::CommonHeader& header);
            friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream&, Packet::CommonHeader& header);
    };
private:
    PacketType _type;
    int _state;
public:
    friend QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream&, const Packet& packet);
    friend QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream&, Packet& packet);
};
}
```

And here goes the Ciode

```
#include "packet.h"
using namespace DG;
QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& stream, const Packet& packet){
    stream << packet._state << packet._type;
    return packet.serialize(stream);
}
```

Comment: How come the second parameters for operator>>() are const?

Comment: Oh! Ya ya Thank YOU ... I just copy paster the operator<< and change it to operator>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason for the `no match for 'operator>>'` error is
that there isn't any match for the `operator>>`, at least not in
the code you've shown.  The only `operator>>` and `operator<<`
in the code you've shown are for `Packet::CommonHeader` and for
`Packet`.  Nothing for a `quint32`, nor for a `QTime`, nor for
a `PacketType`, nor for an `int`.

For that matter, the implementations you've shown us are for
`Packet::CommonHeader` and `Packet`; the classes, however, are
in namespace `DG`, and not in the global namespace.

That could also explain the reason why `friend` isn't working.
The operators you've declared as friend are in namespace `DG`,
those you define are in the global namespace (and are thus
completely unrelated functions).

Comment: Doing `DG::operator<<` in cpp solved the friend Problem. But its `DG::operator<<` not Global `operator<<` So would it work for operator overloading ?

Comment: The compiler will find it anytime either of the arguments somehow implicate `DG`; e.g. if `QDataStream` is in `DG`, always.  Otherwise, you can make `::operator>>` etc. `friend`, or you can provide a public member function `print` or whatever, and call that from `operator<<`, thus avoiding the need of `friend`.

Comment: But `QDataStream` is not in `DG`

Comment: In which case, you probably don't want the `operator<<` et al. in `DG` either, and should make `::operator<<` and `::operator>>` friend (or provide public `print` and `scan` functions which they call).

Answer (score 0):

First remove the const from the rhs parameters of in the >> operators as you are modifying them.